# Inline flexbox overflow using gaps

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm triyng to align some element with flexbox

I have a simple container that is set to inline-flex, and inside I put some elements that have to wrap when the height is bigger than the container height

If i don't use any gaps everything works fine, but if I put a column-gap the elements are overflowing the parent container

Screenshot:

[image: The overflowing element]

I'm not setting any width for the elements, so they should adapt accordingly to the contained items.. why with gaps this seems not to work, and how can I solve the problem?

```css
.button-group-btns {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;  
    border: 1px solid red;   
    max-height: 70px;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    column-gap: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button-group-btns">
  <div>Apri sempre per la modifica</div>
  <div>Personalizza</div>
  <div>Aggiungi ad area</div>
  <div>Diagnostica di sicurezza</div>
  <div>Filtro avanzato</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It seems the behavior depends on the browser. In Firefox, it overflows regardless of `column-gap`, but in Chrome (Edge, Opera) removing the gap causes the div width to adjust itself correctly.

Comment: a very old limitation that is only partially resolved

Answer (score -1):

It’s nothing to do with the gap. I have removed the gap but the content still overflows.

[image]

```css
.button-group-btns {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column;  
    border: 1px solid red;   
    max-height: 70px;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
}
```

```html
<div class="button-group-btns">
  <div>Apri sempre per la modifica</div>
  <div>Personalizza</div>
  <div>Aggiungi ad area</div>
  <div>Diagnostica di sicurezza</div>
  <div>Filtro avanzato</div>
</div>
```

Comment: For me your snippet shows no overflow in chrome and edge, as expected. So the problem are the Gaps